# Update SharePoint list field using powershell based on Date comparison

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I am currently try to update SharePoint field (Dropdown field called Overdue to Yes if the dateFormat field is equal or less than current date. At this stage, it does not change the value. Is there anything that i missed. Please refer the code i have below. Thanks

```
if((Get-PSSnapin | Where {$_.Name -eq "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"}) -eq $null) {
    Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell;
}

$SPWeb = Get-SPWeb "http://contoso/sites/test";
$List = $SPWeb.Lists["Catalog"];
$currentDate = Get-Date (Get-Date) -format dd/MM/yyyy;
$items = $List.Items;
foreach ($item in $items) {

    $deadline = $item["TA Deadline"];
    $dateFormat = Get-Date $deadline -format dd/MM/yyyy;
    #if date Format is less or equal than current date then update the Overdue drop down field to yes
    if($dateFormat -le $currentDate)
    {

        $item["Overdue"]  = "YES"
        $item.Update()

    }
}
$SPWeb.Dispose();
```

Comment: Does $item["Overdue"] show as "YES" after running the line $item.Update() ? (but just doesn't persist into database/show in browser)

Comment: i think the problem with this if($dateFormat -le $currentDate). If i removed it should work fine. Date comparison seems not working

Comment: Yeah, if the code never gets in that if statement, then it for sure won't work. 

Comment: The problem is that you are comparing two strings with -le. You want to keep them as datetime objects. then that if statement will work. Current date is easy `$currentdate = Get-Date`. Just need to figure out how to calculate the date you retrieve from `TA Deadline`

Comment: `$dateFormat = [datetime]$deadline`  should do it

Comment: answer updated with new code to try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to supply an index/numerical numerical value for the choice. See the blog post [here](https://snowburnt.blogspot.com/2009/08/programmatically-working-with.html).

As it mentions you could do:

```
$item["Overdue"] = 0; #assuming 0 == YES
```

Or

```
$item["Overdue"] = $list.Fields["Overdue"].GetFieldValue("YES");
```

---

New code for the datetime logic

```
if((Get-PSSnapin | Where {$_.Name -eq "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"}) -eq $null) {
    Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell;
}

$SPWeb = Get-SPWeb "http://contoso/sites/test";
$List = $SPWeb.Lists["Catalog"];
$currentDate = Get-Date;
$items = $List.Items;
foreach ($item in $items) {

    $deadline = $item["TA Deadline"];
    $dateFormat = [datetime]$deadline
    #if date Format is less or equal than current date then update the Overdue drop down field to yes
    if($dateFormat -le $currentDate)
    {

        $item["Overdue"]  = "YES"
        Write-Debug $item["Overdue"]
        $item.Update()

    }
}
$SPWeb.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 0):

if the Overdue column is a yes/no field (Boolean) I guess You can either do like Dana V suggested, so:

```
    $item["Overdue"] = 0
```

or

```
    $item["Overdue"] = $true
```